# Attempting to Create a User Login for Clojure / Korma / PostgreSQL site

Tags: postgresql, clojure, noir, korma

I am completely stuck on where to start with getting a log-in area for a Clojure site I am building (for fun).

I've looked at several resources, which I'll post below, mercilessly copy/pasted code, and the closest I can get is one of two situations:

The login page takes the login but says that the login failed, though, as far as I can tell, the login matches.

Or I get this error: **No method in multimethod '->sql' for dispatch value: null**

I'm not sure how to interpret the above error: is this specifying that I need a multi-method or is it specifying that I need to check for null? The null requirement makes no sense at all. I'm not really asking but if anyone wants to give an explanation, that is great.

I tested the output by comparing the results-to-select queries from raw non-hashed data, I've went through 5 variations on this theme, using everything from page-to-page calls to creating new defpartials, multi-methods, defn, etc.

Sources I have used (unfortunately, I can't list all of them being a first-time poster):

This one uses Clojure -> Korma -> PostgreSQL, but the code doesn't seem to work for multiple users?
http://www.vijaykiran.com/2012/01/17/web-application-development-with-clojure-part-2/

This one shows how to use Noir and PostgreSQL (Yes, I am using Noir):
https://yogthos.net:11794/blog/23-Noir+tutorial+-+part+2

The 4Clojure site, but that one uses CongoMongo:

The Heroku Twitter clone, but no mention of how to create logins for one person, much less several.

I also bought Programming Clojure from O'Reilly Press, but once again, nothing about how to create a log-in area.

**FIRST EDIT:** I was asked to create a github repository of a stand-alone site. This includes a working "Account Creation" area that is found in the welcome.clj file and only a form of the Login area in login.clj.

I was attempting to get some of the same errors working as I had last night and also attempting to get this working before I uploaded the files. I don't have any reasonable starting points yet, thus there is no beginning implementation as of yet. I'm seriously embarrassed at the solutions I've been coming up with, thus I don't want to post them. I get conceptually what I should do, but for some reason, I can't seem to translate this. This is my first github account: my background is Python, Scheme a'la SICP, and some Python + PostgreSQL marketing program I built.

**SECOND EDIT:** Ack! I can't seem to get the thing to work at all... Yeah, I spent well over 20 minutes (hours) on this one, so I have just have to admit that I don't yet have the requisite knowledge to accomplish this, no matter how many sources I look to. I committed the updated files and all the odd things I tried, including all the variations on login box to running raw SQL. The closest I can come is getting it so that I don't get any errors, but no evidence at all that someone is logged in. Thanks so much for the help and suggestions. I'll most certainly return to this later.

https://github.com/dt1/noirKormaLogin

Comment: It wouldn't be possible without looking at your code. You can probably put the code on github and give a link here.

Comment: Do you really need to implement login yourself? Consider using JSSE authentication in the container (assuming you're running within a container), or using SASL. Let something else handle the password juggling for you and just accept authenticated credentials from the container.

Comment: Also, if you're storing passwords, please make sure they're properly salted hashes. Never store unencrypted plain text passwords, and if at all possible don't store encrypted passwords at all, just salted hashes you can use to verify that the user knows the correct password.

Comment: If you post a small amount of code that can build as a standalone application or Clojure module of functions, someone might try to build it and help figure it out.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to work on the stand-alone right now. I'll upload to github and link to the source tonight.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for those thoughts. I'm not particularly married to any solution. I am using the noir.util.crypt which uses bcrypt. I wasn't planning on storing passwords as raw text. Adding salt should  be trivial once I get the other stuff out of the way. Of course, if everyone thinks that using JSEE / SASL, etc. are better solutions, I can work on adding that in. I'm not a security expert by any measure.

Comment: @dizzystar Storing properly salted and hashed passwords is OK, and since it looks like Noir doesn't use a servlet or EE container, probably much easier too. I just wanted to make sure because I'm seeing lots of people who don't know passwords 101 on SO lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I see.  First, in `datapass.clj`, you're creating an entity with no content.  I'm not sure how Korma handles that.  It's trying to thread results as inputs to other functions, so I could see how `nil` gets introduced there.

Secondly, you'll need something to handle the login post.  `(defpage ...)` only handles GET requests by default.  You'll need a separate `defpage` to handle the post.  Something along these lines:

```
(defpage [:post "/login"] {:keys [user-name pwd]}
  (if-let [user (db/find-user user)]
    (if (noir.util.crypt/compare pwd (:password user))
       (do
         (noir.session/put! :some-key some-value)
         (noir.response/redirect "/success"))
       noir.response/redirect "/failed-to-login"))
  (noir.response/redirect "/failed-to-login"))
```

`session/put!` is how you put data into the session.  The default is to use an in-memory store.  You'll need to add Ring middleware to use [persistent sessions](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Sessions) (look at Session Stores).

Also, as luck would have, someone just posted an authentication app for Noir... you may want to take a look: https://github.com/xavi/noir-auth-app